# Loop for reading the content of two files

Tags: python, loops

I have two files: one contains images, and the other includes segmentations. I could read both by running the following command:

```
import glob
nrrd_filenames = glob.glob('/Users/mostafa/Desktop/PyRadiomics/Labeled Segmentation/*')
nrrd_filenames.sort()

image_filenames = glob.glob('/Users/mostafa/Desktop/PyRadiomics/Image/*')
image_filenames.sort()
```

But when I want to run this command:

```
for i,file in enumerate(nrrd_filenames):
   cmd='pyradiomics '+file+' '+image_filenames[i]+' -o results'+str(i)+'.csv -f csv'
   os.system(cmd)
```

I will get this error:

```
usage: pyradiomics image|batch [mask] [Options]
pyradiomics: error: unrecognized arguments: /Users/mostafa/Desktop/PyRadiomics/Image/CT_A0257.nrrd
usage: pyradiomics image|batch [mask] [Options]
pyradiomics: error: unrecognized arguments: /Users/mostafa/Desktop/PyRadiomics/Image/CT_G0045.nrrd
```

It seems the code cannot read the content of the `image_filenames`.

Comment: Folders not files ?

Comment: It's unclear from `usage: pyradiomics image|batch [mask] [Options]` what arguments are required by the `pyradiomics` command. You're trying to pass it two filenames separated by a space character and a bunch of options. Obviously that is not correct as the error message makes clear. In order to fix this you need to pass the arguments correctly to the command, but it's unclear what usage format is required.

Comment: Your code is creating command it this basic format: `pyradiomics file1.nrrd file1.img -o results0.csv -f csv` which does **not** match the usage information being displayed. It's not clear where the segmentation file should be supplied.

Comment: Yes, that is right. The issue was about the creation of that command. Now, this has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two file paths:

`/Users/mostafa/Desktop/PyRadiomics/Labeled Segmentation/*` is the path for nrrd files.
`/Users/mostafa/Desktop/PyRadiomics/Image/*` is the path for image files.

Your invalid path error is an nrrd file in the image directory, `pyradiomics: error: unrecognized arguments: /Users/mostafa/Desktop/PyRadiomics/Image/CT_G0045.nrrd`

An additional problem you may encounter is the space in your directory name. You should replace spaces with underscores or use quotes when constructing the command. Something like `cmd='pyradiomics "'+file+'" "'+image_filenames[i]+'" -o results'+str(i)+'.csv -f csv'` should work.

Comment: Thanks so much. Your suggestion solved the issue.